# Is there a word in Esperanto for "lightsaber"?

Tags: translation

From Star Wars, the word *lightsaber.*

For those who might not know, in Star Wars a lightsaber is pretty much a glowing blade of laser light that slices through anything. I know that *luma* or *hela* might be a part of it. And, would *saber* be *hakglavo* or *sabro*?

In French, it's *un sabre laser*, if that helps any.

Comment: This question is harder than it looks. Strictly speaking, a saber has a single-edged blade, but I'm pretty sure a lightsaber is supposed to cut from any direction, and in various places it is called a *laser sword*. In other languages, the translation is based on the "rule of cool" and sometimes it is just called a lightsword *(lumglavo)*.

Comment: Now that you know what a lightsaber is in Esperanto, it's time to get your [I-am-your-father-hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-am-your-father) - before the end of the Winter Bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Lumsabro* should work. Esperanto was designed with creating words from basic elements in mind.

Comment: Or "lumglavo", since it isn't technically a saber (which, according to the dictionary entries I read, has a curved blade and a single cutting edge).

Comment: I would like to see an example of *lumsabro* actually used in context.

Answer (score 6):

As the father of some once-small children who played with them in Esperanto, I've been saying *lumglavo* for years without even thinking of it. Turns out there's a Wiktionary page for it.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lumglavo

Answer (score 1):

There is a public translation project for that:
https://eo.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tradukprojektoj:Star_Wars

The current proposition from lightsaber is *lumglavo*

Answer (score 0):

According to wiki, a light saber is also called an energy sword, laser sword, or beam sword https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_sword

Ligna glavo = Wooden sword

Energia glavo = Energy sword

Luma glavo = Light sword

Comment: "Energetic sword" and "Luminous sword". This was discussed a little bit at this question: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/word-construction-with-an-adjective/

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Are you saying that the examples given are incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. A wooden sword is wooden, but a light saber is not light. Therefore, "ligna glavo" is correct but "luma glavo" is not.