# Ĉu oni povas kunigi vortojn per aliaj kategoriaj finaĵoj, ol "-o"?

Tags: word-formation, akademia-vortaro

Mi lernis ke Esperanto permesas kunigi leksemojn nur per

- "-o-" inter la partoj (lunolumo)
- "-" inter la partoj (lun-lumo)
- neniu inter la partoj (lunlumo)

Kaj ankaŭ ke kiam oni uzas numeralojn, la "-a-" afikso estas permisita por montri la ordnaturon de la radiko. Ezemple "triafoje" distingiĝas ol "trifoje".

Sed en [AKTOJ de la AKADEMIO 1968-1974 - Baza Radikaro Oficiala](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/aktoj/aktoj2/bro.html#notoprunto), mi trovas kunligadon per "-e-": "prunte = per prunto (per tia kontrakto) kaj prunti = manifestiĝi per prunto, do la verbo restas same neŭtralsignifa kaj povas esti precizigita per esprimoj kiel deprunti, alprunti, aŭ pruntepreni/pruntedoni".

Do la demando estas, ĉu oni ĉiam povas uzi "-e-", kaj ankaŭ "-a-" kiel kunigilo? Aŭ eĉ "-i-" aŭ "-u-" kiel rilata al la verba signifo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PMEG havas [longan diskuton](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/antauelementoj.html#i-pce) pri la diversaj situacioj kie aliaj finaĵoj ol *-o-* estas permesataj por ligi radikojn.

Pri *-e-* ĝi klarigas jene:

> Se la antaŭelemento estas vorteto (tia vorto, kiu ne bezonas finaĵon), oni normale ne uzas ligan finaĵon. Je bezono oni tamen povas uzi ligan E-finaĵon: *postsigno* → *postesigno* (faciligas la elparolon), *postulo* → *posteulo* (faciligas la komprenon). Tio tamen okazas nur tre malofte.
>
> …
>
> E kiel ligfinaĵo aperas iafoje, kiam la antaŭelemento estas la radiko MULT: *multe-nombro*. La E-vorto *multe* estas ofte uzata kvazaŭ ĝi estus O-vorto.

Pri *-a-* ĝi rekomendas ke ĝenerale oni ne metu ĝin por ligi la vortojn kaj se la prononco estas tro malfacila oni prefere uzu du vortojn anstataŭe.

La *-i-* ja estas uzata ekzemple en *pagipova*. Tamen ĝi diras ke oni povus egale uzi *pagopova* se oni substantivigas la verban radikon. Tamen tio povas esti konsiderata pli kiel frazetvorton.

Se la kunligita vorto estas unuigo de frazo anstataŭ de nur radikoj, ĝi sekvas aliajn regulojn kiujn PMEG nomas [vortigo de frazeto](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/frazetvortigo.html). En tia vorto la eblaj finaĵoj estas pli multaj.

Mi supozas ke *-u-* povus esti uzata en tia frazetvorta kaj PMEG eĉ havas ekzemplon:

> “*Ne forgesu min!*” → [*ne forgesu min*]-(floro)-O → *neforgesumino* = la florspeco miozoto (la nomon kaŭzis la blua koloro de la miozotoj, kiu estas simbolo de ama fideleco)

Vidu ankaŭ la rilatan demandon [When is -o- added between roots in kunmetaĵoj](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/when-is-o-added-between-roots-in-kunmeta%C4%B5oj).

Answer (score 7):

Pri via fina demando - ĉu oni ***ĉiam*** povas uzi "-e-", kaj "-a-" (aŭ "-i-" aŭ "-u-" ) kiel kunigilo - mi respondas ke ne. Oni povas fari tion **nur kiam la senco de la vorteroj permesas**.

"Pag**i**pova" estas bona vorto, ĉar ĝi venas de la frazero "povi pag**i**", sed "libr**i**breto" ne estas bona vorto por "breto por libroj."

Estas pli da ekzemplo en la sekcio pri "Vortigo per A-finaĵo aŭ E-finaĵo" en la jena artikolo de PMEG.

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/frazetvortigo.html