# Why do some compound words leave out the "o"?

Tags: word-formation

I'm working through [this exercise](https://learn.esperanto.com/en/01/ekzerco1/). It has *labortablo* and *skribotablo* as two of the words. Why isn't the former *laborotablo* instead? Furthermore, would *labora tablo* and *skriba tablo* be equivalent, respectively?

Comment: I think, its euphony: When the emerging consonant cluster is easy to pronounce, the o is dropped, but it is left when a hard-to-pronounce consonant cluster like -bk- emerges.

Comment: Duplicate of https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/when-is-o-added-between-roots-in-kunmetaĵoj, as already mentioned in the first answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is -o- added between roots in kunmetaĵoj?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/when-is-o-added-between-roots-in-kunmeta%c4%b5oj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I know for sure. In this particular case I imagine *skribotablo* is preferred because *skribo* conveys the act of writing while *skrib-* is for the broader concept of write, but I have seen *skribtablo* accepted as an alternative​ form.
*Skriba tablo* on the other hand would imply that it is a 'written table' instead of a 'writing table', which sounds much less like a desk than it does some kind of sketch.
I imagine difficulty/simplicity of pronunciation also play a role in which one should be used.

Edit: You can probably find out more [here](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/2465/951).

Comment: The omission of _-o-_, with an exception not of interest here, has no relation to the structural semantics of the compound word, so this part of the answer is wrong. Unfortunately the person asking has accepted it as best answer. The two other answers are correct.

Answer (score 9):

I would assume it's simply a phonological matter: you cannot easily pronounce **skribtablo* because of the two successive plosives. It is of course perfectly possible, but *skribotablo* is somewhat easier to say.

With *labortablo* that's not the case, and *laborotablo* adds an extra syllable which is not necessary to ease pronunciation.

So, it's the [principle of least effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_effort) that is at play here.

Comment: It might just be my native language at play here, but I can say skribtablo with no effort required. Labortablo however ...

Comment: Yes, true -- these things very much depend on what you are used to from your native language. My perspective is from a Germanic language background, and I also don't find it that hard. But it's all relative: with the 'o' it is a bit easier. And that is probably all that it takes.

Answer (score 5):

The -o is usually omitted unless its presence eases pronunciation...

- minejo de oro = gold mine
- or(o)minejo = gold mine

---

- forko por fojno = fork for hay
- fojn(o)forko = hay fork

---

- leviĝo de la suno = rising of the sun
- sun(o)leviĝo = sunrise

http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq040.html#sec4-1-2